Interpretation of Poisson regression model (outcome variable - dietary diversity)
I would like to get some insights on how to interpret the Poisson model using the results shown in the picture.

This is how I interpreted it: For every one unit increase in the number of cooked food street vendors, the estimated MFD would increase by 1.61 units. Similarly, for every one unit increase in the number of kiosks and mom-and-pop shops/ cereal shop, the estimated MFD would increase by 2.33 and 2.49 respectively. A one unit increase in modern restaurants/ fast food/ bakery is associated with an estimated increase in MFD by 2.59, while that of wholesalers by 1.15. A one unit increase in hyper-/supermarkets and tabletop/ mama mboga is associated with an increase in MFD by 4.19 and 2.37 respectively.
For example, the estimated Market Food Diversity for hyper-/supermarkets is 3.68 higher than that of ambulant vendors/street hawkers/mobile vendors. Similarly, the estimated MFD for cooked food street vendors/roadside catering, kiosks/duka and mom-and-pop/cereal are 1.53, 2.28 and 2.41 respectively higher than for ambulant vendors. For modern restaurants/fast food, the difference in estimated MFD with that of ambulant vendors was 2.22. The differences in estimated MFD between tabletop vendors and wholesalers with ambulant vendor/street hawkers/mobile vendors are 2.28 and 1.42 higher.
Is my interpretation correct? If not, what is the correct interpretation?

Can you write down the equation estimated by the GLM?  That would give you some insight(s)...

Your interpretation would seem reasonable if your regression was using the identity link, but that is not the default for Poisson GLMs in R

You are interpreting your coefficients as if your predictors are numeric (i.e., "one unit increase"), but your code and output suggests that all of your predictors are categorical. These require a special interpretation. The interpretation of each coefficient (after exponentiation) is the ratio of the expected count for that category to the expected count for the reference category holding other variables in the model constant. We don't know what the reference categories are for your variables because they don't have coefficients corresponding to them.
For example, the coefficient on RegroupVenTypeCooked food street vendor is .475, which means the expected MFD for a unit with RegroupVenType equal to "Cooked food street vendor" is $\exp(.475) \approx 1.608$ times the expected MFD for a unit with RegroupVenType equal to the reference category when the values of Income and food_space are held constant. That is, the coefficient compares two hypothetical units: one at the value corresponding to the coefficient and one at the value corresponding to the reference category, with the same value of the other predictors.
In order to correctly interpret the coefficients, you need to know the reference category for each predictor. If the comparison between each level and the reference category is not of interest, you need to do more work to estimate quantities that are actually useful to you. Indeed, you should start with quantities that you want to estimate first, figure out how to estimate those quantities, and then implement the model that best fits your data rather than starting with a model and hoping the coefficients from the model correspond to quantities of interest. I recommend using the marginaleffects package to better understand what conclusions your model implies and to estimate interpretable quantities that will be useful for your analysis.
